# Migrating report app from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have looked through a several forums and cannot find an answer to my specific question so don't hurt me if I have asked something that has been answered before. I have a SSRS report project that was created in Visual Studio 2005 (then upgraded to 2008) before my time at my company and i need to upgrade it to 2013 Visual studio. I know normally you just open the file and use the migration wizard, however i get an error because my Visual Studio 2013 does not recognize the .rptproj file and thus does not fully migrate the solution. I have a copy of VS Shell 2010 that was able to upgrade it to 2010 but this did not help me to migrate it to 2013. Is there a way i can migrate this over without having to buy more copies of VS to do a stair step migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first check if the [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) module is installed on your computer.

Comment: Glad you gave me that link, I found a thread after i started this question that had a link similar but to the 2012 version of this toolset but I was too busy yesterday to look for the 2013 one. Thanks loads for not just skipping over my question.